# ModX Revo: Display one resource within another

Tags: resources, modx, modx-revolution, getresource

I want to display the contents of one resource within another. I think this is possible with getResources but I cannot get it working for me. I have:

```
[[getResources &parents=`-1` $resources =`16`]]
```

but nothing displays. I have made sure all resources have been published and that getResources is installed correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - that's exactly what getResources is for, you are not getting anything because you have a few syntax errors.

[[getResources &parents=`-1` $resources =`16`]]

should be:

[[getResources? &parents=`-1` &resources =`16` &tpl=`myTpl`]]

the '?' tells Modx that there will be parameters, $resources will get ignored & if you don't specify an &tpl parameter, getResources will just dump the raw array to your page.

Comment: Ah thanks! So I must use a template even if I just want the content and nothing else?

Comment: Yes, generally speaking getResources is used to grab a group of resources and needs to loop over them for output.  If you have just a single field to retrieve, try using getResourcefield .... [also omitting the &tpl in getResources is useful for debugging ;)]

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to use a template. This code is working fine:

`[[getResources? &resources=1 &tpl=@INLINE [[+content]] &includeContent=1 ]]`